# sudo: setuid must be root

Tags: 10.10, sudo

I changed the permissions of my `/usr` directory to `777` by mistake and now my system give this error whenever I try to use sudo:

```
sudo: setuid must be root
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: should be on serverfault, but i'll tell you now your best bet is to re install OS - all the setuid and setgid bits will be gone, short of finding out what all of those are and running `chmod +sS` you'll want to reinstall

Comment: i had the same problem 2 weeks ago. reinstalling is the only solution.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your error, you didn't simply changed the permissions of /usr to 777, you did it recursively which is a more serious and problematic change.

Unless you have backups of your system directories, your best option is just to reinstall.

Comment: With the caveat that you *could* manually reset every file of every sub-directory to the right setting by manually comparing it to a good Ubuntu install.

Answer (score 0):

Go to recovery console (reboot, and chose recovery console ) and type

chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo

then

chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo

then

reboot

Comment: It'll work for `sudo` only, but other binaries are affected as well and are likely to cause issues too.